# Como Printar o passo a passo

Tags: java, printf

Tenho o seguinte programa que faz o seguinte, vc insere as regras(V,T,P,S), através de 1 arquivo e depois vc insere a palavra(GLUD) para ver se ela faz parte ou n da linguagem que está na regra, e ai o programa retorna um Sim ou um Não caso a palavra faça ou n parte, só que agora eu Gostaria de saber como fazer para printar o passo a passo do método CheckWord(); no arquivo verificador.java.

Para assim quando não for aceita a palavra, mostrar aonde que foi o erro.

PS: isso é um trabalho de linguagens formais e autômatos que lé linguagem GLUD

Programa em execução:

[image: Programa Rodando.]

> Main.java

```
package verificador;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Verificador verificador = new Verificador();
        String word;
        String g = "";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        if(args.length > 0){
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        }else{
            System.out.print("Não ha parametros, digite o nome do arquivo: ");
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in.nextLine()));
        }
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            g += line;
        }
        verificador.readGrammar(g);
        System.out.println("Gramatica: " + g.replaceAll("\\s+"," "));
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Digite a palavra: ");
                word = in.nextLine();
                if(word.length() == 0){
                    return;
                }
                word = word.replaceAll("\\s+|λ|#", "");
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                return;
            }
            if (verificador.checkWord(word)) {
                System.out.println("Sim");
                word.length();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Não");
            }
            //verificador.ShowRules(word);
        }
    }
}
```

> Verificador.java

```
package verificador;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Verificador {

    private final ArrayList<State> states;
    private final ArrayList<String> alphabet;
    private final ArrayList<Rule> rules;
    private State inicial;

    public Verificador() {
        states = new ArrayList<>();
        alphabet = new ArrayList<>();
        rules = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setStates(String states) {
        states = states.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        for (String e : states.split(",")) {
            this.states.add(new State(e));
        }
        this.states.add(new State("DEFAULT", true));
    }

    public State getStateByName(String name) {
        for (State e : states) {
            if (e.getName().equals(name)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setAlphabet(String alphabet) {
        alphabet = alphabet.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        this.alphabet.addAll(Arrays.asList(alphabet.split(",")));
        this.alphabet.add("#");
        this.alphabet.add("λ");
    }

    public boolean checkLetter(String letter) {
        for (String l : alphabet) {
            if (l.equals(letter)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setRules(String regras) throws Exception {
        regras = regras.replaceAll("\\{|\\}", ""); // Tira {}
        for (String regra : regras.split(",")) {
            String[] r = regra.split("->");
            if (r.length != 2) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada");
            }
            State estadoAtual = getStateByName(r[0]);
            if (estadoAtual == null) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada - Estado invalido1:" + r[0]);
            }
            try {
                for (String transicao : r[1].split("\\|")) {
                    State estadoDestino;
                    String letter = transicao.substring(0,1);
                    if(!checkLetter(letter)){
                        throw new Exception("Regra mal formata - Caracter invalido: " + transicao.substring(0,1));
                    }
                    if (transicao.substring(1).equals("")) {
                        estadoDestino = getStateByName("DEFAULT");
                    } else {
                        estadoDestino = getStateByName(transicao.substring(1));
                        if (estadoDestino == null) {
                            throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada - Estado invalido:" + transicao.substring(1));
                        }
                    }
                    this.rules.add(new Rule(letter, estadoAtual, estadoDestino));
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw new Exception("Regra mal formatada");
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Rule> getPossibleRules(State estado, String elemento) {
        ArrayList<Rule> regras = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Rule r : this.rules) {
            if (r.getState() == estado && r.getElement().equals(elemento)) {
                regras.add(r);
            }
        }
        return regras;
    }

    public void setInicial(String inicial) throws Exception {
        State estado = getStateByName(inicial);
        if (estado == null) {
            throw new Exception("Estado inicial invalido");
        }
        this.inicial = estado;
    }

    // ({A,B,C}; {a,b,c}; A -> aB | bA | cA | λ, B -> aB | bC | cA | λ, C -> aB | bA | λ; A)
    public void readGrammar(String gramatica) throws Exception {
        gramatica = gramatica.replaceAll("\\(|\\)|\\s+|\\n", ""); // Tira parentesis e espaços

        if(gramatica.contains("=")){ // Tira o nome da gramatica do inicio
            gramatica = gramatica.split("=")[1];
        }
        gramatica = gramatica.replaceAll("\\},", "\\};"); // Substitui a , por ;
        String[] g = gramatica.split(";"); // Quebra partes da gramatica
        if (g.length != 4) {
            throw new Exception("Gramatica mal formatada");
        }
        setStates(g[0]);
        setAlphabet(g[1]);
        setRules(g[2]);
        setInicial(g[3]);
    }

  public void printRules() {
        for (Rule r : rules) {
            System.out.println(r.toString());
        }
    }

    boolean checkWord(String palavra) {
        return checkWord(palavra, inicial);
    }

    boolean checkWord(String palavra, State estadoAtual) {
        if (palavra.isEmpty() && estadoAtual.getIsFinal()) { // terminou a palavra
            return true;
        } else if (palavra.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        ArrayList<Rule> possiveisRegras = getPossibleRules(estadoAtual, String.valueOf(palavra.charAt(0)));
        for (Rule r : possiveisRegras) {
            if (checkWord(palavra.substring(1), r.getDestiny())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

> State.java

```
package verificador;

public class State {
    private String name;
    private boolean isFinal;

    public State(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public State(String name, boolean isFinal){
        this.name = name;
        this.isFinal = isFinal;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean getIsFinal() {
        return isFinal;
    }

    public void setIsFinal(boolean isFinal) {
        this.isFinal = isFinal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if(name.equals("DEFAULT")){
            return "";
        }
        return name;
    }

}
```

> Rule.java

```
package verificador;

public class Rule {
    private String element;
    private State state;
    private State destiny;

    public Rule(String element, State state, State destiny){
        this.element = element;
        this.state = state;
        this.destiny = destiny;
        if(element.equals("#") || element.equals("λ")){
            this.state.setIsFinal(true);
        }
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public State getDestiny() {
        return destiny;
    }

    public void setDestiny(State destiny) {
        this.destiny = destiny;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return state + " -> " + element + destiny;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta fazer dessa forma:

```
boolean checkWord(String palavra) {
    System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", "Palavra", "Estado");
    System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", palavra, inicial);
    return checkWord(palavra, inicial);
}

boolean checkWord(String palavra, State estadoAtual) {
    System.out.format("%-10s %-10s\n", palavra, estadoAtual);
    if (palavra.isEmpty() && estadoAtual.getIsFinal()) { // terminou a palavra
        return true;
    } else if (palavra.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    ArrayList<Rule> possiveisRegras = getPossibleRules(estadoAtual, String.valueOf(palavra.charAt(0)));
    for (Rule r : possiveisRegras) {
        if (checkWord(palavra.substring(1), r.getDestiny())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

O resultado final será uma tabelinha com o seguinte formato:

```
Gramatica: Gram = ({S, A, B}, {a,b}, { S -> aA, A -> bB, A -> λ, B -> aA, },S)
Digite a palavra: aba
Palavra    Estado    
aba        S         
aba        S         
ba         A         
a          B         
           A         
Sim
```

O **%-10s** no system.out.format está dizendo que a string **s** deverá ocupar 10 espaços, com alinhamento à esquerda (**-**). Tirando o sinal de **-** o alinhamento seria à direita.

Comment: Seria interessante explicar essas formatações utilizadas no printf, as vezes o OP ou outro usuário pode não entender muito bem.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, realmente não pensei nos iniciantes.